# Error when trying to display a timer into button text

Tags: python

When i run this code everything seems to work fine, then when i click my blue buff button where I'm expecting my time countdown to start being displayed the button text instead changes to  function my_time at 0x000000... etc. some memory location im struggling to find a solution. If its unclear what im trying to do is have the text Blue Buff change to the to a countdown.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import time

class Application(Frame):
    @staticmethod



def my_time(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
min = 4
sec = 59
while sec <=60:
    os.system('cls')
    print min, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
    time.sleep(1)
        sec -= 1
    if sec == 0:
         min -= 1
         sec = 59
    elif min == 0:
         min = 4

    def my_time2(self):                    # tries to display my_time method into the button font, doesnt seem to work.
        self.Button1["text"] = str(self.my_time)





    def createButtons(self):                      # creats a button
        self.Button1 = Button(self)
        self.Button1["text"] = "Blue Buff"
        self.Button1["fg"]   = "Blue"
        self.Button1["command"] = self.my_time2    # suppose to implement countdown in button text when click.
                            # currently problematic?                
        self.Button1.pack({"side": "left"})



    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)    # initializes window
        self.pack()
        self.createButtons()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: your `my_time` function needs proper indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import time

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)    # initializes window
        self.Button1 =  Button(self, text="Blue Buff", command=self.my_time)
        self.Button1.pack()
        self.pack()

    def my_time(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
        min = 4
        sec = 59

        while sec <=60:
            os.system('cls')
            print min, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
            self.Button1.configure(text="{}:{}".format(min,sec))
            self.Button1.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            sec -= 1
            if sec == 0:
                 min -= 1
                 sec = 59
            elif min == 0:
                 min = 1

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()#
```

Using your own code just set command to my_time and update the Button1:

```
class Application(Frame):

    def my_time(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
        min = 4
        sec = 59
        while sec <=60:
            self.Button1.configure(text="{}:{}".format(min,sec))
            self.Button1.update()
            os.system('cls')
            print min, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
            time.sleep(1)
            sec -= 1
            if sec == 0:
                 min -= 1
                 sec = 59
            elif min == 0:
                 min = 4

    def my_time2(self):                    # tries to display my_time method into the button font, doesnt seem to work.
        self.Button1["text"] = str(self.my_time)

    def createButtons(self):                      # creats a button
        self.Button1 = Button(self)
        self.Button1["text"] = "Blue Buff"
        self.Button1["fg"]   = "Blue"
        self.Button1["command"] = self.my_time    # suppose to implement countdown in button text when click.
                            # currently problematic?
        self.Button1.pack({"side": "left"})
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)    # initializes window
        self.pack()
        self.createButtons()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting `self.Button1["command"] = self.my_time2` in which `self.my_time2` is not a an attribute, but rather a function.  That would be why the numbers look all wonky, is because its displaying a memory address and not the `str(self.my_time)` that you would expect.  Perhaps you meant to **invoke** `my_time2()`

*EDIT 1

changing line 25 to

```
    self.Button1["text"] = str(self.my_time(self))
```

Also what you have written in my_time will print to stdout, and not actually update the button (which is what I think you want?), but i'll let you figure that out as the designer.

Comment: I understand what your saying, makes sense. How would it look it recoded though, im a bit confused

Comment: That would just cause the same problem , and when clicked it would also display a memory location.

Comment: That doesn't work either all it does is take away the click functionality of the button and immediately displays a memory location.

Comment: alright my bad, the line I changed to get the countdown working was changing `self.Button1"text" = str(self.my_time(self))`, again this was an issue with invoking the command and not just setting something equal to it

Comment: thanks , not to be rude but i had already figure that out through experimenting what i wanted to know was how to get the text in the button to be displayed as the time but you did give me a hint at least thanks.

Comment: Nice!  I'm glad you were able to work through your bugs, its the best way to learn.  Cya on the Rift. ;P